# how to delete old folders and files that where created or modified x days ago?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
DAYS=1
find /directory/tmp/* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
find /directory/tmp* -type f -mtime +3 -delete
find /directory/tmp* -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find /directory/tmp -mtime +3 -exec rm -Rf -- {} \;
find /directory/tmp -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find /directory/tmp -type f -mtime +2 -delete
find /directory/tmp -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find /directory/tmp* -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
find /directory/tmp* -mtime +$DAYS -exec rm {} \;
find /directory/tmp* -mtime +$DAYS -exec rm {} \;
```

I have tried all of those statements above, none of them work.
it's either am getting a -exec error OR the error for using the -delete
how to solve this ? i just want to delete all the directories and files that were created or modified in a given day, like 3 days ago 20 days ago

Note: some of those did work by pasting manually in the terminal.but when i already place it inside the shell file and run it like `sh myscript.sh` , that's the time am getting the errors that's why I said none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

First run below command and see if the files are getting listed:-

```
find /directory/tmp -name "*" -mtime +2 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Here `"*"` means all. You can write `"*.tmp"` **if** files which ends with .tmp extension.

If yes, then try:-

```
find /directory/tmp -name "*" -mtime +2 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: I tried the first one and I still get the same error when I placed it inside a .sh file `find: missing argument to `-exec'` but when i ran it in the terminal, it's ok..any idea why it fails when ran inside a .sh file ?